# Where is documentation on CFBundleAlternateIcons?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11, xcode9, xcode9.4

I have managed to get Alternate Icons working by adding explicit Icons as individual icons (e.g. Tennis@1x.png, Tennis@2x.png, Tennis@3x.png) and adding appropriate referencing entries in Info.plist under the key CFBundleAlternateIcons.
However, for the main icon I am using entries in Assets.xcassets and would have expected to be able to use a similar set of icons for each of the alternatives.

Is this possible or desirable? If so, how?

If not, what sized Icons should I be supplying to cover all devices? At the moment I have just a set 20x20 icons in three sizes. For the iPad I have a set of two 76 x 76 icons.

The Array CFBundleIconFile provides an array, but I cannot seem to get anything more than "Item 0" to have any affect, and that seems to need to be identical to the name of the Dictionary it is contained in. Surely, there must be some functionality?

And surely there must be a list of what size icons should be provided?

Comment: This official document link : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname?language=objc
Also demo on the github : https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/AlternateIconTest

Comment: Unfortunately, that documentation on the function provides a link Information Property List Key Reference which connects to a document which states "Important: This document is no longer being updated. For the latest information about Apple SDKs, visit the documentation website." and does not appear to have any info on these keys. I am asking if there is more info documented elsewhere. The AlternateIconTest is a great starting project, but I already have an App that does that much; I am looking for more information about the info keys.

Comment: were you able to get this working in the end?